# fastest way to iterate matrix of known dimensions

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering what the fastest way to iterate through a matrix is in c/c++.

The best method i've come up with so far is to map the matrix to a single dimension.

Then use pointer arithmetic, any other method that might be faster?

Dimensions are known at run time but not compile time, matrix is fully populated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#define XMAX 500
#define YMAX 400
#define ZMAX 300

int main()
{
    srand(0);   
    register double sum = 0;
    register int i;
    register int j;
    register int k;

    double *arr_ptr;
    arr_ptr = new double[XMAX*YMAX*ZMAX];

    for (i=0; i<XMAX*YMAX*ZMAX; ++i)
    {
        *(arr_ptr+i) = rand()/double(RAND_MAX);
    }

    clock_t start, finish;
    start = clock();

    for (i=0; i<XMAX; ++i)
    {
        for (j=0; j<YMAX; ++j)
        {
            for (k=0; k<ZMAX; ++k)
            {
                sum += *(arr_ptr+i*YMAX*ZMAX+j*ZMAX+k);
            }
        }
    }

    finish = clock();
    std::cout << "sum: " << sum << "\telapsed: " << finish - start << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    delete[] arr_ptr;
}
```

Comment: You have it right.  Represent it as a contiguous 1D array, and iterate using a linear index.

Comment: I don't think `*(array+i)` is any faster than `array[i]`… The compiler will translate it the same way.

Comment: @Simon is correct, `array[i]` is defined as being identical to `*(array + i)`, so there is no difference between the two forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the bounds are even constants, so normal three dimensional arrays would work with this, be it C or C++.

Then, C and C++ are really different languages on what is concerned dynamically allocated arrays with variable bounds, don't mix them up. For C++ use vector classes and such things. They are made for this and they should be efficient.

In C, since C99 there are VLA, variable length arrays. Contrary to urban myth they may be quite efficient, if you don't allocate them on the stack. Use `malloc` as for any big chunk of memory in C.

```
double (*arr_ptr)[XMAX][YMAX][ZMAX]
  = malloc(sizeof(*arr_ptr));

for (register size_t i=0; i<XMAX; ++i)
  for (register size_t j=0; j<YMAX; ++j)
    for (register size_t k=0; k<ZMAX; ++k)
       (*arr_ptr)[i][j][k] = rand()/double(RAND_MAX);

.

free(arr_ptr);
```

Modern processors have quite complex addressing schemes, so it might not be necessary to effectively do the complete index calculation. Your compiler usually knows better than you.

Then, to be efficient it might be much more important how you declare and handle your loop variables. Use the correct types for indexing, `size_t` is the correct unsigned type for that. `int` may easily overflow when you compute 3-D flattened indices and having a signed type here makes not much sense.

Then declare those variables as local as possible, makes things clearer for you and the compiler.

`register` is just a contract with the compiler that you never will take the address of such an index. Usually this doesn't improve things a lot. But may prevent you from doing inefficient things when you modify your code later.

And last but not least, if you really worry about efficiency, check what your compiler produces. E.g `gcc` has the option `-S` to produce the intermediate assembler. Read it instead of speculating about efficiency.

Answer (score 7):

Why bother with the three nested for-loops? You could just do

```
for (i=0; i<XMAX*YMAX*ZMAX; ++i)
{
    sum += *(arr_ptr+i);
}
```

Comment: Or just `sum += arr_ptr[i]`.  And be aware that `XMAX*YMAX*ZMAX` might overflow the type for very large arrays (in which case a cast to `size_t` is appropriate).

Comment: the nested loops are to simulate the intended usage, should have made that more clear

Comment: @user615174: you're accessing what is fundamentally a linear buffer in linear order; I think a single for loop is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 3):

This is 650ms faster than your code for `XMAX 500`, `YMAX 400` and `ZMAX 100`, run 100 times, according to ideone.com compiler.

```
double *p_current, *p_end;

p_current = arr_ptr;
p_end = (arr_ptr + XMAX*YMAX*ZMAX);
while(p_current != p_end) {
    sum += *p_current++;
}
```

See: [old version](http://www.ideone.com/Y4qcD), [new version](http://www.ideone.com/4IKXM)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it doesn't matter because the compiler will optimize it anyway. So `arr[i][j][k]` and `*(arr_ptr+i*YMAX*ZMAX+j*ZMAX+k)` will be equally fast.

Comment: Not true in general. A contiguous array will benefit from cache locality. A dynamically allocated nested array won’t be contiguous so you’ll incur a runtime overhead for cache misses. Of course, when the dimensions are known at compile time and a static array is created, that will be contiguous and then you are right.

Comment: yeah this i tried the 3 dim array, single dimension was around 40% faster in iteration, if you count dellocation signle dimension is like 1000% faster

Comment: the dimensions are not known at compile time only at run time

Comment: @user615174: What makes you think that the array would not be contiguous?

Comment: This answer is only correct if using C99 and the array is allocated on the stack as a contiguous array ... but then it would be arr, not arr_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV uses pointer arithmetic:

```
double *ptr = arr_ptr;
for (i=0; i<XMAX*YMAX*ZMAX; ++i)
{
    sum += *ptr++;
}
```

I guess it might be a little faster somehow. Try it and show us the timings!

Comment: There’s no reason why pointer arithmetic should be faster here. The compiler should generate the exact same code for indexed access and your pointer code. Hoisting the multiplication out of the loop on the other hand is potentially a good idea.

Comment: If your talking about the `XMAX*YMAX*ZMAX` multiplication, *this* for sure will be simplified by the preprocessor!

Comment: The multiplication you're referring to is XMAX*YMAX*ZMAX? I've always wondered about this, if most compilers will optimize the multiplication away by precalculating it, since XMAX YMAX and ZMAX expand to integer constants. Or, if they were actual variables, but didn't change in the loop, I wonder if most will precalculate the result?

Comment: It's faster and gives the same performance gain as [the solution I proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046449/fastest-way-to-iterate-matrix-of-known-dimensions/5046727#5046727) =)

Answer (score 1):

```
double *ptr = arr_ptr;
for (int i=XMAX*YMAX*ZMAX; i>0; --i)
{
    sum += *ptr++;
}
```

Comparing the loop variable to zero, instead of to some constant may save one or two clock cycles for each iteration (for example, using JNZ instruction on intel CPUs)

Comment: I tried it the same way it did in my answer, and comparing to zero gives no noticeable gain, but is faster than the original of course. http://www.ideone.com/OhsS8

Comment: Don't do it like this. `int` is usually 32 bit on modern systems and `size_t` is 64 bit. The initial value might easily overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that needs to be said is that stack allocated multidimensional arrays are stored in memory (in C and in C++) in row major order. Namely matrix[ 2 ][ 2 ] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } } is going to be stored in memory just like you had actually declared an array[ 4 ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } and the `matrix[][]` syntax is just syntactic sugar for `*( matrix + i * 2 + j)`.

So the fastest way to traverse the matrix depends on how you traverse it: in row major order or column major and how big the matrix is:

- if the entire matrix can fit in the CPU cache than the traversal order doesn't matter;
- if the matrix is bigger than the CPU cache than doing row major traversal cause less  CPU cache misses.

The best way to know if you have a performance problem in matrix operations and what causes it is to profile your code.

Answer (score 0):

For very large blocks of data, consider parallel operations.  In this case, a sum can be computed with a gather operation -- the form of which will depend on the parallel framework you choose.